# Android flashlight app

Tags: android, flashlight

I can't find a straight forward answer on how to build a flash light app in Eclipse Android. How would I create this?

Comment: Do you mean, just making the screen 100% white?

Comment: No. I mean using the LED flashlight that some phones have. I know how to make a white screen already. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad and probably no one will write a tutorial just for you. Having said that, here are the tips which may help you:

If you want a flashlight application simulated by a screen painted in white, I'd recommend reading the (very simple) sources of *android-flashlight* which does exactly that. The project sources are available here: http://code.google.com/p/android-flashlight/

If you want a flashlight using camera's LED, I'd recommend reading sources of the *search-light* application (available in Google Play) which does exactly that. The sources are located here: http://code.google.com/p/search-light/

If you want to develop the application from scratch then there is no easy way but learn the very basics of Android platform. There are tons of tutorials available on the Internet which will guide you through the process of creating your first, minimal application - just google it. The platform is described and documented well. It also has guides on how to build applications. All these resources are located here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html